# Edition for Schumann's Novelletten

Tags: piano, editions

I am looking for a good edition for the Novelletten Op. 21 by Schumann. I saw the Peters edition and the Henle edition. Is there a particular edition that is recommended for the Novelletten?

I am looking for an edition that is accurate to the intentions of the composer and that has useful information such as on fingering, on differences of previous editions and, if possible, on interpretation and on the context of the music.

Comment: The question neither specifies, in which respect the edition is desired to be *good*, nor mentions it special intentions you may have, so the default *learning to play* has to be applied.

Comment: Different editions play an important role on the study and interpretation of the music. This is not a question on  transcribing or finding a particular song. I have included additional information on what makes a good edition.

Comment: *Urtext* is about being close to the original - this will typically not include much fingering level information (the composer may often have written for himself/herself). While the editors notes may supply information concerning corrected notes, I have yet to find a score supplying much concerning interpretation and context. For this secondary literature exists, which easily fills whole books on its own.

Comment: Good editions compare interpretation marks that appeared in the manuscript and that sometimes were changed in subsequent editions. This kind of information is important because it suggests points that can have different readings. This is about music, practice and interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Caveat: I can't examine the editions directly, so my comments are based on information available online plus experience with other scores from these publishers.)

Both Peters and Henle have Urtext editions, meaning both claim to be as faithful as possible to Schumann's original intentions.

Peters is edited by [Hans Joachim Köhler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Joachim_K%C3%B6hler); Henle by [Ernst Herttrich](https://www.henle.de/en/about-us/contributors/ernst-herttrich/) (Editor) and [Walther Lampe](https://www.henle.de/en/about-us/contributors/walther-lampe/) (Fingering).

I generally find Henle to be printed more clearly, on better paper, and with easier to read layout. On the other hand, they are also more expensive.

A (very) brief survey on [imslp](https://imslp.org/wiki/8_Novelletten,_Op.21_(Schumann,_Robert)) and "the internet" suggests that there isn't much debate about the score itself, which would imply both are accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was surprised to see that this question was considered off topic, although this is a “music: practice and theory” forum.

Comment: Curious to know if you found an edition you're happy with. Also, I see you never got an explanation of why the question was closed. The reason given is a bit misleading, but recommendations for products to buy are off topic.

Comment: I like the Henle editions and I chose this one. However, I will never know from this site if there are other editions that complement Henle or that reflect in a better way the intentions of Schumann. This kind of discussion had to be encouraged here. I expected more from this site.

Comment: @Andre It's a continual point of contention, and the boundaries are fuzzy. Personally, I wish more people would make use of the chat room, which would be a near ideal forum for question which merit discussion and debate.